# StaticImage in GatsbyJS keep format SVG

Tags: svg, gatsby, gatsby-image

i have this code

```
     <Link to="/">
            <StaticImage
                loading="eager"
                src="../images/logo.svg"
                alt="Logo"
            />
        </Link>
```

gatsby-plugin-image reformat my svg on WebP format.
Its posiblle keep format SVG and stil using `<StaticImage>` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you know in advance your image is going to be a svg, you can import your svg directly & use a regular img tag:

```
import logo from '../images/logo.svg'

export const Page = () => <Link to="/"><img src={logo} /></Link>
```

In the example above, webpack will copy your `logo.svg` to the static dir & return the path as the string.

Comment: or prevent a request and embed it in HTML

Comment: @tfrei Gatsby will inline assets as base64 string below certain kb threshold IIRC — but for SVG, embedding directly in HTML will certainly help saving some extra bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If your `svg` is animated prefer [`gatsby-plugin-react-svg`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/) :

```
import Icon from "./path/assets/icon.svg"

// ...

<Icon />
```

As far as I know you can't keep the `svg` format with `<StaticImage />` nor `<GatsbyImage />` as their main purpose is to convert images in the presumed best formats.